# How to get SUM of custom column in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I have this admin

```
class UserMemberAdmin(AdminImageMixin, BaseUserAdmin):
    """User Member."""
    change_list_template = "admin/ggbeats/user_member/change_list.html"
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'get_member_gems_balance', 'gems_transaction_link', 'topup_payment_link', 'date_joined', 'is_staff')
    ordering = ['-date_joined']

    search_field = ['username', 'email']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'birth_date', 'gender', 'picture',)
        }),
        (_('Game info'), {
            'fields': ('game_id', 'nickname', 'is_gamer', 'is_alert', )
        }),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'role'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined', 'confirmed_at')
        }),
    )
```

and I add custom column like this to this admin

```
def get_member_gems_balance(self, obj):
        """Get member gems balance."""
        return gems_transaction_services.get_member_gems_balance(obj)
    get_member_gems_balance.short_description = 'GEMS'
```

Now, I want to add total of my custom column 'get_member_gems_balance' in `{% block result_list %} {{ block.super }} Gems on this page: {{ cl.gems_count }} {% endblock %}` from `change_list.html`

I create this in admin

```
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_results(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyChangeList, self).get_results(*args, **kwargs)
        q = self.result_list.aggregate(gems_sum=Sum('get_member_gems_balance'))
        self.gems_count = q['gems_sum']
```

and called in my UserMemberAdmin

```
def get_changelist(self, request):
        return MyChangeList
```

But it turns out error like this

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'get_member_gems_balance' into field. Choices are: birth_date, confirmationcode, confirmed_at, date_joined, email, first_name, game_id, game_server_member, gameservertoken, gems_transaction_member, gems_transaction_reference, gender, groups, id, inboxthread, is_active, is_alert, is_gamer, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, nickname, password, phone_number, picture, role, sent_messages, social_auth, topup_payment_member, user_permissions, user_threads, username
```

I think it because get_member_gems_balance is not actual field in that model. How can i overcome this?
Thankyou for any help

Comment: did you have a @property() decorator on get_member_gems_balance?

Comment: no i didnt have, am i suppose  to add that property? @vpdiongzon

Comment: thats right, it detects that its not a property.

Comment: so i just add @property above def get_member_gems_balance ?